# Can not set value when value has double quote as default in dropdownlistfor asp.net core using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

if value is not contains double quote then work fine but only problem with value contains double quote in below code. Value :- 1/2\"

`$('select#listspec_0__qty option[value = "1/2\""]').attr("selected", true);`

Comment: Use `prop()` instead of `attr()`

Comment: not working in prop() also

Comment: Can you please add the HTML to the question so we can recreate the problem. All the suggestions made so far are reasonable, but clearly you have other issues in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Just use backquotes

```
$(`select#listspec_0__qty option[value = "1/2"]`).attr("selected", true);
```